# Mulesoft Transformation Problem for Syste, and process apis with database with two tables

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a database with two tables
Table1:NameStream
Table2:StreamSubject

NameStream looks lika this:
Name......Stream
Tathagata Science
Arpan     Commerce

StreamSubject looks like this
Stream.....Subject
Science....Math
Science....Physics
Commerce...Accounts
Commerce...Tax

I made two system APIs. One is fetching data from NameStream and showing the whole table in Json format in browser, another one is doing same with the second table. Now a made a Process API to perform orchastretion. The goal is I will enter name is query parameter which will do like this, Name->Stream->Subject. How to do it? I am struggling with the datawave transformation and filter part. Point to be noted is that I din not specify any queryparameter in the system APIs

Comment: Please share at least your input JSONs and expected outputs plus anything you have tried and fails. There is not enough information here to work with otherwise.

Comment: ok, I will, just wait